# Could Not Access File using phpMailer

Tags: php

I'm Using phpmailer to send mail.
Recieving mail fine but the attachment not attached in it.

When I debug it. it gives me the error.

"Could not access file: upload_images/images.jpg"

i have a folder upload_images in which i have an image name images.

here is my code...

```
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {
    require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
    $mail->port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = "info@example.com";
    $mail->Password = '******';
    $file_name = $_FILES["attc"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["attc"]["tmp_name"];
    $path = '/upload_images/';
    //move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$file_name);
    $mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com','From_name');
    $mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com','To_name');
    $mail->addReplyTo('abc@gmail.com','From_name');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAttachment("upload_images/images.jpg","images.jpg");
    $mail->Subject = "Testing well";
    $mail->Body = 'This is Body Part';
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo "<script>alert('Email Sent Success!')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('".$mail->ErrorInfo."')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is this folder located, in relation to the (main) script file?

Comment: it's located in the root folder. in which this php file located

Answer (score 0):

You should use an absolute path. For example, if `upload_images` is inside the document root, you may use:

`$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload_images/images.jpg","images.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path.

```
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {
require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
$my_path ="upload_images/images.jpg";
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
$mail->port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = "info@example.com";
$mail->Password = '******';
$file_name = $_FILES["attc"]["name"];
$tmp_name = $_FILES["attc"]["tmp_name"];
$path = '/upload_images/';
//move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$file_name);
$mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com','From_name');
$mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com','To_name');
$mail->addReplyTo('abc@gmail.com','From_name');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->AddAttachment($my_path);
$mail->Subject = "Testing well";
$mail->Body = 'This is Body Part';
if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "<script>alert('Email Sent Success!')</script>";
}
else{
    echo "<script>alert('".$mail->ErrorInfo."')</script>";
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Use the following and path for file in the variable $my_path

```
if (isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])) {

    //use the path
    $my_path = "/upload_images/images.jpg";

    require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "mail.domain.com";
    $mail->port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = "info@example.com";
    $mail->Password = '******';
    $file_name = $_FILES["attc"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["attc"]["tmp_name"];
    $path = '/upload_images/';
    //move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$file_name);
    $mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com','From_name');
    $mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com','To_name');
    $mail->addReplyTo('abc@gmail.com','From_name');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAttachment($my_path,'images.jpg');
    $mail->Subject = "Testing well";
    $mail->Body = 'This is Body Part';
    if ($mail->send()) {
        echo "<script>alert('Email Sent Success!')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('".$mail->ErrorInfo."')</script>";
    }
}
```